# Notification Center in iOS5

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5

Is New Notification Center feature alternative to APN(Apple Push Notification Center)?can we give notificaion from webserver to this?

Comment: It's pretty funny that you're asking an iOS 5 question but tag it with [iphone-sdk-4.0].

Answer (score 4):

No one with detailed knowledge of this can answer without breaking their NDA with Apple.

From the keynote it looks as though the Notification Center is just a new way of organising the existing system of notifications (i.e., push and local). You would have to look in the iOS Developer Center to find the technical details.

Comment: And be a paid member doing so.